# How to get transaction id in multi channel funnel top conversion path report

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, google-analytics-filters

I'm having a problem generating a report in Google Analytics regarding top conversion path report in multi channel funnels part of GA. My main goal is to show transaction ids aside from top conversion paths so I could see in which transactions has AdWords participated.

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm trying to achieve almost the same thing as you. Thanks.

Comment: Actually not yet. I'm close to a solution. I'll post it here in a couple of days.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: No, still haven't.

Comment: There is a solution. You can use the Google spreadsheet reporting API and when you start setting up the parameters they should go like: Type:mcf, View (Profile) ID / ids: ga:123456789, Start date:11/01/2017, End Date:11/30/2017, Metrics: mcf:yourMetric, Dimensions: mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath,mcf:transactionId

Just run the report afterwards.